# Find the centre of a spot using 2d gaussian fit

Tags: python, 2d, curve-fitting, gaussian, scipy-optimize

I need to find the centre of the bright spot in sequent images like this:[cross correlation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9eKd.png)

My idea is to fit the image with a 2d gassian function in order to find the maximum. I use scipy.optimize.curve_fit for this. I created a simulated data for fitting and here the fit works well.

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import cv2

#define 2d gaussian function

def gauss2dFunc(xy, xo, yo, sigma):
        x = xy[0]
        y = xy[1]
        return np.exp( -((x-xo)*(x-xo) + (y-yo)*(y-yo)) / (2.*sigma*sigma) ).ravel()
    

xvec = np.array(range(200))
yvec = np.array(range(200))
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xvec,yvec)
initial_guess = [100,100,10] #xo,yo,sigma

#create data with gaussian distribution

def gauss2d(shape=(200,200),sigma=20):
    m,n = [(ss-1.)/2. for ss in shape]
    y,x = np.ogrid[-m:m+1,-n:n+1]
    h = np.exp( -(x*x + y*y) / (2.*sigma*sigma) )
    h[ h < np.finfo(h.dtype).eps*h.max() ] = 0
    h = h / h.max()
    return h[:200, :200]


#add noise
gauss2d_noise = gauss2d() + 0.2*np.random.normal(size=gauss2d().shape)

#fit with 2d gaussian function
popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(gauss2dFunc, (X, Y), gauss2d_noise.ravel() , p0=initial_guess)


fit = gauss2dFunc((X,Y), *popt)


f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)
axarr[0].imshow(gauss2d_noise, cmap='gray')
axarr[1].imshow(fit.reshape(200,200), cmap='gray')
```

[left:simulated data - right:fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfGeM.png)

But as soon I try to fit real image it fails.

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import cv2

#define 2d gaussian function

def gauss2dFunc(xy, xo, yo, sigma):
        x = xy[0]
        y = xy[1]
        return np.exp( -((x-xo)*(x-xo) + (y-yo)*(y-yo)) / (2.*sigma*sigma) ).ravel()
    


xvec = np.array(range(200))
yvec = np.array(range(200))
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xvec,yvec)
initial_guess = [100,100,10] #xo,yo,sigma

#read iamge

image = cv2.imread('cor.png', 0)   
print(np.shape(image))


#fit with 2d gaussian function
popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(gauss2dFunc, (X, Y), image.ravel() , p0=initial_guess)


fit = gauss2dFunc((X,Y), *popt)


f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)
axarr[0].imshow(image, cmap='gray')
axarr[1].imshow(fit.reshape(200,200), cmap='gray')
```

[left:real image - right:fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMvSW.png)

I am new in Python and I have no idea why it doesn't work. It would be great if someone would help me.

Comment: What is the max value in `image`?

Comment: Hi, the max value of the image is 226

Comment: And what is the max value returned by `gauss2dFunc`?

Comment: The max value of gauss2dFunc is 0.9999.....